# If using South, does it even matter what the underlying database is?

Tags: django

Today I have started my first steps into postgresql, since its recommended by the Django team.

I came across several issues, that I solved patiently one by one.

1) Creating tables under postgresql requires to login as a different OS login, from which you don't even know the password.  Fine, I found the solution and created the database.

2) After running syncdb, you can't simply execute a simple insert sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO App_contacttype (contact_type, company_id) VALUES ('Buyer', 1),('Seller', 1);
```

Since Django creates it with quotes the table becomes case sensitive, hence it has to be like this:

```
INSERT INTO "App_contacttype" (contact_type, company_id) VALUES ('Buyer', 1),('Seller', 1);
```

But the problems seem never to end. Now suddenly the execution of the insert script says

```
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(40)
SQL state: 22001
```

In MySQL this was no problem. I don't know, right now I am getting a bit of cold feet, maybe I should just stick to MySQL.

The only reason I was considering postgresql was that some research suggested postgresql has much better support for changing Schemas along the way than MySQL.

However considering http://south.aeracode.org/ would take away all the pain of syncing Schemas, would I even need to worry about Schema changes at all no matter what the underlying database is?